# Public object in cloud storage bucket isn't accessible through load balancer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-cdn

I have CDN setup for my Google CLoud Storage bucket. I have uploaded a public object, you can see it with the public link here: https://storage.googleapis.com/staging.twinkle-4acfc.appspot.com/example_out_message_bg.9.png

So in order for the CDN to work, as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42691577/how-to-use-google-cloud-cdn-to-access-google-cloud-storage-public-objects), I need to access the bucket through the load balancer.

Okay, so I setup the load balancer, this URL is directed to the bucket, and it is a public object, but the response contains an XML access error.

http://130.211.26.19/stagemedia/example_out_message_bg.9.png

In fact, you can change the path to anything, just try /a, the error is the same. Is the load balancer set up incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your object needs to match the whole path, which in this case is "stagemedia/example_out_message_bg.9.png". Try creating an object with that whole name, including the "stagemedia/" part.

Comment: Thanks. I see you work on GCS - is this how load-balancing buckets is envisioned to work long term? It seems strange to couple the load balancing rules to the object path in the bucket. I imagine that if I choose to go forward with CDN, I'll just create one LB per bucket.

Comment: Follow-up: seeing as how load balancers are expensive, I wouldn't want to run 2 LB's. In fact, at the moment I decided not to use LB or even go through Cloud CDN because of the cost of LB.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to have your object publicly shared as well, as described in docs here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/adding-a-backend-bucket-to-content-based-load-balancing#configuring_a_bucket